# lerna run start --parallel on specified ports

Tags: node.js, monorepo, lerna

Hello I am using lerna to manage my mono repo and to run cross app testing, I would like to start all my apps at the same time on multiple ports with one command.

I have tried

```
lerna run start --parallel --scope package1 --scope package2 --scope package3
```

package1 starts but then package2 fails because package1 is already on port 3000. I would like to specify the ports as follows:

```
package1 -> 3000
package2 -> 3001
package3 -> 3002
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running that command in your main package file, right?
How do you run your start script in each module you create?

You should specify the port as well for each app in your script, i.e:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "PORT=3000 BROWSER=none craco start"
}
```